# returning a FutureBuilder as the result of a FutureBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an add friend page in Flutter/Firebase. I used a StreamBuilder to see the changes of the username input. Then I used a **FutureBuilder as the result of the StreamBuilder** to get my List of User. To verify that the users aren't already in thisUser's friend list, I'm **using an other FutureBuilder as the result of the first one**. And I still do the same for the friend requests.

It works but I'm pretty sure that not the right way. Could someone explain me how to do that more properly?

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: controller.usernameStream.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      String usernameSearched = snapshot.data!;
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: _userRepo.getUsersStartsByUsername(usernameSearched),
        builder: (context, snapshotUsers){
          if(snapshotUsers.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
            if (snapshotUsers.hasData){
              return controller.futureBuilderFriends(thisFireUser, snapshotUsers);
            } else {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.noUsers)),
              );
            }
          }
          return Container();
        },
      );
    }
    return Container();
  },
)
```

```
FutureBuilder<List<String>> futureBuilderFriends(User? thisFireUser, AsyncSnapshot<List<U.User>> snapshotUsers) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _userRepo.getFriendsId(thisFireUser!.uid),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshotFriends) {
        if (snapshotFriends.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if(snapshotFriends.hasData){
            return futureBuilderMyFriendRequests(thisFireUser, snapshotFriends.data!, snapshotUsers);
          } else {
            return futureBuilderMyFriendRequests(thisFireUser, [], snapshotUsers);
          }
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

```
FutureBuilder<List<String>> futureBuilderMyFriendRequests(User thisFireUser, List<String> friends, AsyncSnapshot<List<U.User>> snapshotUsers) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _userRepo.getFriendRequestsId(thisFireUser.uid),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshotFriendRequests) {
        if (snapshotFriendRequests.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if(snapshotFriendRequests.hasData){
            return buildAddFriends(context, snapshotUsers.data!, thisFireUser, friends, snapshotFriendRequests.data!);
          } else {
            return buildAddFriends(context, snapshotUsers.data!, thisFireUser, friends, []);
          }
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are on vanilla architecture. Please make use of bloc or Riverpod and use the transfrom functions and emit the states accordingly

Comment: Actually I'm using GetX, the futureBuilder functions are in my controller. I didn't understood what you meant because I don't want to observe any value here. I have a users collection with friendRequests and friends subcollections. When I'm looping on my list of users, I have to verify that the user that is searching isn't in the friendRequests (sent by the user that is searching) of the user that I want to display (and I'm also doing the same for friends and for "myFriendRequests", the request sent by the displayed user).